# Why is the stress component in a tensor related to deformation along two dimensions

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-strain

While trying to derive the constitutive laws of Newtonian fluids, I came across this equation:
$$\tau_{ij} = \mu\left(\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}+\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_i}\right)$$

I understand that stress is proportional to rate of strain of a body. However, I do not understand why $\partial v_i/\partial x_j$ is related to stress on the surface (force along $\hat j$), and the normal to the surface is $\hat i$ . Shouldn't such a stress only depend on $\partial v_j/\partial x_i$ because $\tau{_i}{_j}$ is shearing the fluid element along an axis parallel to $j$-axis only?

Also, I read on the link below that $\tau_{ij}$ = $\tau_{ji}$ if the fluid volume is infinitesimal. I don't understand how this works. Don't $\tau_{ij}$ and $\tau_{ji}$ produce different deformations in the fluid element?
I would appreciate some help on these questions.

https://web.mit.edu/2.25/www/pdf/viscous_flow_eqn.pdf

Thanks for the replies. I have read [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/665102). Although I understand the derivation for strain, I do not understand why we attribute the rate of change of strain(in two dimensions) to only one component of stress tensor. Isn't that strain the result of two components of stress tensor deforming the body in two different directions?

Thanks for bringing out the ideas of tensorial and engineering and strain. I understand why I was confused. I want to get one more thing clarified: can I say that by the symmetry of the stress tensor, $\tau_{ij}$ = $\tau_{ji}$, the strain caused by both the components of the stress tensor is the same in magnitude? Also, it acts on deforming a different angle of the fluid element. Is this right?

Comment: For the answers to all your questions, see Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Chapter 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is shear strain related to change in diagonal](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665102/is-shear-strain-related-to-change-in-diagonal). Both terms are needed because Nature doesn't care how you orient your orthogonal axes $i$ and $j$.

Comment: I read the post suggested above(https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665102/is-shear-strain-related-to-change-in-diagonal) and the book Tranport phenomena. I still don't understand why we take stress on one surface to be rate of change of strain in a plane? I think that it should be half of rate of change of strain because two shear stress tensors are contributing to that strain( deformation of a rectangle into a parallelogram). Why is my thinking wrong? If only one of those shear stress tensors existed, would deformation be the same?

Comment: I edited my question to explain my question after reading the suggested post(https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665102/is-shear-strain-related-to-change-in-diagonal)

Comment: Do you understand that $\tau_{ij}$ requires fully four forces to avoid acceleration? See the animations [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/645549/146039).

Comment: Yes, I understand that forces must be balanced to avoid acceleration. Sorry for confusing this in my previous post. However, I do not intuitively understand the fact that rate of strain is proportional to sum of velocity gradients in both the axes. Would you mind explaining when both velocity gradients are required and when one would suffice with diagrams? Also, what effect does the component of stress tensor on another face play in the deformation of the body? Thanks

Comment: If you’ve already read the previous post and understand why both $\partial x_i/\partial x_j$ and $\partial x_j/\partial x_i$ are needed (the reasoning is the same as that for $\dot x=v$), then I guess I don’t understand your question. Could you edit your question to show what you think the expression *should* look like? This may make it easier to discuss a counterexample.

Comment: For example, if you think the expression should read $\tau_{ij}=\mu(\partial v_i/\partial x_j)$ alone, consider the example of an element that’s shearing but happens to be oriented such that vertical or $j$-axis lines remain vertical, implying no horizontal velocity $v_i$ (see the second animation in the previous question). You’d calculate a shear stress of zero, which is a contradiction. Does this get at what you’re asking about?

Comment: As another example, if you think a factor of 1/2 should be inserted, note that by definition, $\mu$ couples the shear stress with the rate of change of the *engineering* shear strain, corresponding to the rate of change of the corner angles of the differential element. The engineering shear strain is twice the tensorial shear strain.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thanks for your replies. I understood the reason for the equation. I would appreciate one more clarification I mentioned in the edited question. Thanks

Comment: $\tau_{ij}=\tau_{ji}$ from inspection of the definition. They are identical and produce the same strain. As discussed earlier, to avoid acceleration, if you apply a load pointing in the $i$ direction on the surface with normal $j$, you must also apply a load pointing in the $-i$ direction on surface with normal $-j$, and you must apply loads in the $j$ and $-j$ directions on the surfaces with normals $i$ and $-i$, respectively. Thus, $\tau_{ij}$ can't be distinguished from $\tau_{ji}$.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks